# Intermittent "Not a Product" Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, rollbar

We have a website (.Net / jquery / Bootstrap 4), using Rollbar to log Javascript errors. Rollbar is logging an intermittent Javascript error with the message "Not a Product." For the trace, it only includes:

```
File "(unknown)" line (unknown) col 0 in [anonymous]
```

**The error only occurs on Chrome 60, 61, and 62** on **Windows** and **Mac**. Our client information and telemetry do not expose any browser extensions that could be responsible, but I don't know how to rule that out. Is there some way to troubleshoot this, or do we have to assume it's a Chrome extension unless it occurs on other clients?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It was being caused by the "Honey" chrome extension.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember. It was driving me crazy as well. Ended up down some google rabbit hole and saw it mentioned somewhere. It was especially annoying because I was working on an e-commerce application and getting "not a product" errors.

Comment: Yeah that's our issue as well, we spent a lot of time thinking it must be in our FB or Google Analytics or Bing reporting, but it's not.